# In a dictionary whose value is another dictionary, how to change a specific value of the second dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

I have a dict whose key is the name of a spanish recipe and the value is another dictionary which contains key= ingredient and value= qt of that ingredient:

```
new_dic = {
    'Conejo al ajillo': {
        'hoja de laurel': '1',
        'ccs de aceite': '50',
        'cabeza de ajos': '1',
        'vaso de vino': '1',
        'kilos de conejo': '1.5',
        'guindillas': '3'},
    'Pimientos verdes rellenos de codornices.': {
        'ccs de aceite': '80',
        'cucharadas de agua': '2',
        'dientes de ajo': '2',
        'cebolla': '1',
        'cucharada de chocolate rallado ': '1',
        'codornices': '6',
        'cucharada de harina': '1',
        'vaso de jerez seco': '1',
        'pimientos verdes grandes': '6',
        'gramos de sal': '5',
        'gramos de tocino de jamón': '50'},
    'Pollo a la leonesa.': {
        'cucharadas de jerez': '2',
        'huevo': '1',
        'gramos de jamon': '50',
        'gramos de trufa en lata ': '25',
        'ccs de leche': '100',
        'manzana reineta': '1',
        'gramos de menudillos de pollo': '200',
        'gramos de miga de pan ': '100',
        'kilos de pollo': '1.5',
        'gramos de tocino': '50',
        'ccs de aceite': '50',
        'gramos de manteca': '50'},
    'Pollo de corral al chilindron': {
        'ccs de aceite': '150',
        'dientes de ajo': '6',
        'gramos de cebolla ': '400',
        'gramos de harina': '60',
        'hoja de laurel': '1',
        'pizca de pimienta': '1',
        'kilos de pollo': '2',
        'pizca de sal': '1',
        'gramos de tomate frito': '50',
        'gramos de tomates ': '300',
        'ramito de tomillo': '1',
        'pimientos verdes': '2'},
    'Pavo relleno de castanas': {
        'cucharadas de caldo': '7',
        'gramos de castanas cocidas ': '500',
        'cucharada de harina': '1',
        'gramos de magro de cerdo ': '250',
        'gramos de manteca': '100',
        'kilos de pavo tierno': '2.5',
        'cucharadita de pimienta ': '1',
        'pizca de sal': '1',
        'pavo': '1'},
    'Conejo a la castellana.': {
        'cucharadas de aceite ': '7',
        'vaso de agua': '1',
        'vaso de caldo': '1',
        'conejo': '1',
        'cucharada de harina ': '1',
        'gramos de jamon': '50',
        'gramos de manteca de cerdo ': '50',
        'gramos de pan': '150',
        'pizca de sal': '1',
        'vasito de vino blanco': '1'},
    'Gazpacho manchego': {
        'cucharadas de aceite de oliva ': '6',
        'dientes de ajo': '4',
        'gramos de conejo': '400',
        'pizca de pimenton dulce': '1',
        'pizca de pimienta': '1',
        'pellizco de sal': '1',
        'gramos de tomate ': '30',
        'torta manchega': '1'},
    'Lomo de ciervo en salsa de setas y trufa.': {
        'ccs de aceite de oliva': '180',
        'dientes de ajos': '6',
        'gramos de cebollas pequenas': '200',
        'hoja de laurel': '1',
        'filetes de lomo de ciervo de unos ': '12',
        'gramos cada uno ': '75',
        'taza de nata liquida': '1',
        'cucharadita de oregano': '1',
        'cucharadas de pimenton dulce ': '2',
        'pizca de sal': '1',
        'gramos de setas cocidas': '200',
        'cucharaditas de tomillo': '0.5',
        'trufa en aguardiente': '1'}
        ...}
```

And I have create a standardize variable in order to standardize all the quantities to grams.

```
standardize={
        'alcachofas':200,
        'apio': 400,
        'berenjena': 180,
        'berenjenas': 180,
        'cabeza': 150,
        'cabezas': 150,
        'calabacin': 200,
        'cebolla': 75,
        'cebolletas': 75,
        'chorreon': 10,
        'chorreon': 10,
        'chorreton': 10,
        'chorrito': 5,
        'chuchradas':10,
        'cigalas': 80,
        'clavo': 3,
        'clavos': 3,
        'cocochas': 70,
        'codornices': 80,
        'conejo':80,
        'copa':100
         ... }
```

I am trying to create a function that iterates through both, standardize and new_dict and everytime that new_dict contains an ingredient which is in standardize it changes its value by multiplying its old value * the standardize value.

For example, in this first recipe there is "cabeza" which in standardize its value is 150 so I want to transform from this

```
{'Conejo al ajillo': {'hoja de laurel': '1',
  'ccs de aceite': '50',
  'cabeza de ajos': '1',
    ...
```

to this

```
{'Conejo al ajillo': {'hoja de laurel': '1',
  'ccs de aceite': '50',
  'cabeza de ajos': '150',
    ...
```

Because 1*150 is equal to 150 (which means its value in grams).

I have been trying things and I am close but far at the same time i think, this is my code:

```
def stand(dic):
    for e in standardize:
        for i in dic.values():
            for key,value in i.items():
                if e in key:
                    #print(i)
                    #print(key)
                    #print(value)
                    #print(e)
                    value = float(value)*float(standardize[e])
                    print(value)
                return dic
```

It returns the value that I want but I does not change it in new_dict.

Any help please??

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: `value` is merely a variable. You probably want `i[key] = float(value)*...` to have the actual value inside the dictionary change

Answer (score 1):

As the others mentioned, you were creating a new variable `value` instead of updating the associated dictionary. Here is a readable way of accomplishing your goal.

```
def stand(dic):
    # For each recipe and ingredients dictionary
    for recipe, ingredients in dic.items(): 
        # For each ingredient and amount in ingredients dictionary
        for ingredient, amount in ingredients.items(): 
            # Split ingredient into separate words
            for word in ingredient.split(' '):
                # Check if word exists in the standardize dictionary
                if word in standardize: 
                    # If there is a match, then update the ingredient with its new amount
                    dic[recipe][ingredient] = float(amount) * standardize[word]

    return dic

print(stand(new_dic))
```

**Output**

```
{
    "Conejo al ajillo": {
        "hoja de laurel": "1",
        "ccs de aceite": "50",
        "cabeza de ajos": 150.0,
        "vaso de vino": "1",
        "kilos de conejo": 120.0,
        "guindillas": "3"
    },
    "Pimientos verdes rellenos de codornices.": {
        "ccs de aceite": "80",
        "cucharadas de agua": "2",
        "dientes de ajo": "2",
        "cebolla": 75.0,
        "cucharada de chocolate rallado ": "1",
        "codornices": 480.0,
        "cucharada de harina": "1",
        "vaso de jerez seco": "1",
        "pimientos verdes grandes": "6",
        "gramos de sal": "5",
        "gramos de tocino de jam\u00f3n": "50"
    },
    "Pollo a la leonesa.": {
        "cucharadas de jerez": "2",
        "huevo": "1",
        "gramos de jamon": "50",
        "gramos de trufa en lata ": "25",
        "ccs de leche": "100",
        "manzana reineta": "1",
        "gramos de menudillos de pollo": "200",
        "gramos de miga de pan ": "100",
        "kilos de pollo": "1.5",
        "gramos de tocino": "50",
        "ccs de aceite": "50",
        "gramos de manteca": "50"
    },
    "Pollo de corral al chilindron": {
        "ccs de aceite": "150",
        "dientes de ajo": "6",
        "gramos de cebolla ": 30000.0,
        "gramos de harina": "60",
        "hoja de laurel": "1",
        "pizca de pimienta": "1",
        "kilos de pollo": "2",
        "pizca de sal": "1",
        "gramos de tomate frito": "50",
        "gramos de tomates ": "300",
        "ramito de tomillo": "1",
        "pimientos verdes": "2"
    },
    "Pavo relleno de castanas": {
        "cucharadas de caldo": "7",
        "gramos de castanas cocidas ": "500",
        "cucharada de harina": "1",
        "gramos de magro de cerdo ": "250",
        "gramos de manteca": "100",
        "kilos de pavo tierno": "2.5",
        "cucharadita de pimienta ": "1",
        "pizca de sal": "1",
        "pavo": "1"
    },
    "Conejo a la castellana.": {
        "cucharadas de aceite ": "7",
        "vaso de agua": "1",
        "vaso de caldo": "1",
        "conejo": 80.0,
        "cucharada de harina ": "1",
        "gramos de jamon": "50",
        "gramos de manteca de cerdo ": "50",
        "gramos de pan": "150",
        "pizca de sal": "1",
        "vasito de vino blanco": "1"
    },
    "Gazpacho manchego": {
        "cucharadas de aceite de oliva ": "6",
        "dientes de ajo": "4",
        "gramos de conejo": 32000.0,
        "pizca de pimenton dulce": "1",
        "pizca de pimienta": "1",
        "pellizco de sal": "1",
        "gramos de tomate ": "30",
        "torta manchega": "1"
    },
    "Lomo de ciervo en salsa de setas y trufa.": {
        "ccs de aceite de oliva": "180",
        "dientes de ajos": "6",
        "gramos de cebollas pequenas": "200",
        "hoja de laurel": "1",
        "filetes de lomo de ciervo de unos ": "12",
        "gramos cada uno ": "75",
        "taza de nata liquida": "1",
        "cucharadita de oregano": "1",
        "cucharadas de pimenton dulce ": "2",
        "pizca de sal": "1",
        "gramos de setas cocidas": "200",
        "cucharaditas de tomillo": "0.5",
        "trufa en aguardiente": "1"
    }
}
```

You can use `print(json.dumps(stand(new_dic), indent=4))` to have the output formatted in this readable format.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `value = float(value)*float(standardize[e])`, you are telling Python to create a new variable `value` and assign the response there. Thus you're never updating the value in your dictionary.

If you want the result to be assigned back in to the dictionary from which it came, you'd do something like this instead:

```
i[key] = float(value)*float(standardize[e])
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the dictionary itself, not just the `value` variable.

Note that you can simplify your approach by directly testing for dictionary membership in `standardize`, rather than looping over its keys:

```
def standardize_nested_dict(dic):
    for ingredients_dict in dic.values():
        for ingredient, raw_value in ingredients_dict.items():
            if ingredient in standardize:  # No need to use an extra loop for this
                standardized_value = raw_value * standardize[ingredient]
                ingredients_dict[ingredient] = standardized_value  # Update the dictionary explicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here is exactly what you need:

```
for dic in [new_dic[key] for key in list(new_dic)]:
    for ke in list(dic):
        if ke in list(standardize):
            dic.update({ke:str(int(dic[ke])*int(standardize[ke]))})
```